# mod_rewrite rewrite rule required to strip section of route and add to end of query string

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm using an API that puts a unique id in the route and then I need that unique ID moved into my internal routing (so php can work with it).

The url is:

> http://top.level.domain/folder/[UNIQUEID]/index.php

The file on the server to host is actually located at:

> http://top.level.domain/folder/index.php

So I need to turn the original URL into:

> http://top.level.domain/folder/index.php/[UNIQUEID]

Any ideas of a rewrite rule that would do what I need?

([Duplicate question closed on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291661/mod-rewrite-rewrite-rule-required-to-strip-section-of-route-and-add-to-end-of-qu).)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /folder/[^\/]+/index.php
RewriteRule /folder/([^\/]+)/ /folder/index.php/$1
```

Comment: I still get a 404 with that

Comment: Try enabling the rewrite log and see what you get.